# How do I use the @ sign in comments?

Tags: support, faq, comments

I would like to use **@dev @prod** in comments sometimes. 
**@dev** is not a user, it is a drush server alias.

I got the following error message:

> Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified.

Answer (score 2):

If you write "`@dev`" you don't get any error message. Differently, Stack Exchange will think you are referring to a user, and it doesn't allow you to refer to two different users in that way.
The problem is that the software doesn't check if what written after *@* is a username, or not; this means that you get that error even if there aren't users who use "dev" as username.

The alternative is using the backslash, but that would be rendered as `\@dev`, in comments.